# How to register typing.Callable with Python @singledispatch?

Tags: python, python-3.8, callable, dynamic-dispatch

### Background

Suppose I am to implement a simple decorator `@notifyme` that prints a message when the decorated function is invoked. I would like the decorator to accept one argument to print a customized message; the argument **(along with the parentheses surrounding the argument)** may be omitted, in which case the default message is printed:

```py
@notifyme('Foo is invoked!')
def foo():
    pass

@notifyme  # instead of @notifyme()
def bar():
    pass
```

To allow the parentheses to be omitted, I have to provide two implementations of `@notifyme`:

1. The first implementation allows the user to customize the message, so it accepts a string as argument and returns a decorator:

   ```py
   def notifyme_customized(message: str) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable]:
       def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
           def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
               print(str)
               return func(*args, **kwargs)
           return decorated_func
       return decorator
   ```
2. The second implementation is a decorator itself and uses the first implementation to print a default message:

   ```py
   def notifyme_default(func: Callable) -> Callable:
       return notifyme_customized('The function is invoked.')(func)
   ```

To make the two implementations above use the same name `notifyme`, I used `functools.singledispatch` to dynamically dispatch the call to `notifyme` to one of the two implementations:

```py
# This is a complete minimal reproducible example

from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Callable

@singledispatch
def notifyme(arg):
    return NotImplemented

@notifyme.register
def notifyme_customized(message: str) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable]:
    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print(str)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_func
    return decorator

@notifyme.register
def notifyme_default(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    return notifyme_customized('The function is invoked.')(func)
```

### Problem

However, as the code is interpreted by the Python interpreter, it complains that `typing.Callable` is an invalid type:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 20, in <module>
    def notifyme_default(func: Callable) -> Callable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\functools.py", line 860, in register
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid annotation for 'func'. typing.Callable is not a class.
```

I have found [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34498) on Python bug tracker, according to which it seems to be expected behavior since Python 3.7. Does a solution or workaround exist in Python 3.8 I use currently (or Python 3.9 that has been released recently)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you utilize a default argument instead of having the two functions?  You're also using a generic without type parameters which may be why you're getting errors.  You may want to use a `: function) -> function` annotation instead.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Thank you for your comment! But if I use a default argument, I have to write `@notifyme()` when I want to use the default message, and I would like the parentheses be omitted as well (like `@notifyme`)

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley And if I use a `: function) -> function` the Python intepreter complains `NameError: name 'function' is not defined`, but `function` seems to be a built-in symbol so I am confused as well

Comment: Ah, I guess I should've tried the sample before giving feedback!  I'll be back in a few with more comments since I'm curious now.

Comment: Based on [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/#user-api), it looks like you're missing data in your registration.  It doesn't work with ambiguous types such as collections without types (or `Callable` on its own for example).

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Thanks for your effort investigating into this, but I'm afraid I cannot quite get the point. I tried to replace `Callable` with a more specific `Callable[[int], str]` but it doesn't work either. Nor does it work when I explicitly use `@notifyme.register(Callable)` or `@notifyme.register(Callable[[int], str])` :-( And if `Callable` cannot be used, what can I use to register the function type?

Comment: I found a workaround: `def _a(): pass` then `Function = type(_a)` and use that in the places expected for the annotation (`func: Function`).  I did not test whether dispatch works properly, but the code runs. `type(lambda: None)` also returns the internal `function` class.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Thank you for your workaround! It works well, but I cannot still understand why the built-in function type is not designed to be directly accessible. (P.S. Would you like to post your workaround as an answer? I'll upvote and accept it.)

Comment: I've run into a similar issue. It seems that singledispatch from python std lib requires a class as a type. It does not support things like 'list[int]'. I could solve this problem using external lib called multimethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to use `typing.Callable` with `functools.singledispatch`, but I did find a workaround by using a `function` class reference instead:

```py
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Callable

function = type(lambda: ())

@singledispatch
def notifyme(arg):
    return NotImplemented

@notifyme.register
def notifyme_customized(message: str) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable]:
    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print(str)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_func
    return decorator

@notifyme.register
def notifyme_default(func: function) -> Callable:
    return notifyme_customized('The function is invoked.')(func)
```

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable

```
from collections import abc

@notifyme.register
def notifyme_default(func: abc.Callable) -> Callable:
    return notifyme_customized('The function is invoked.')(func)
```

Comment: This solution seems to play better with tools like mypy. Mypy complained that the overwritten `function` object is not a valid type. No complaints with `collections.abc.Callable`

Comment: This is a much better solution. Partials, callable class instances, and probably lots of other callable things are supported by this solution that get rejected by the accepted answer.